# Как принудительно закрыть выпадающий список комбобокса?

Tags: delphi

Добрый день! У меня такая проблема. После выбора значения из комбобокса выполняются долгие вычисления, в результате чего в том месте, где был выпадающий список комбобокса, образуется белое пятно. Можно ли принудительно закрыть выпадающий список комбобокса, чтобы пятна не появлялось?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю расчеты производятся в событии onChange , так первой строкой в процедуре перерисовывайте или форму или сам combobox , а потом уже проводите расчеты.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

Где "выполняются долгие расчёты" добавьте в цикл
Application.ProcessMessages;
чтобы combobox мог перерисоваться и не подвисало всё остальное